# sql join for three tables in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to join three tables in laravel 5.3.I want to join three table and fetch approver name and department name

```
table travel_request
id
approver_id (fk)
department_id (FK) 

user table
approver_id
name

Department table
department_id 
dept_name

query
 $users = DB::table('travel_request')
        ->join('department', 'travel_request.department_id', '=', 'department.department_id')
        ->join('users', 'travel_request.department_id', '=', 'users.approver_id')
        ->select('travel_request.*', 'department.name as dept_name','users.name as approver_name')->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `->join('users', 'travel_request.department_id', '=', 'users.approver_id')`

It should be

```
$users = DB::table('travel_request')
    ->join('department', 'travel_request.department_id', '=', 'department.department_id')
    ->join('users', 'travel_request.approver_id', '=', 'users.approver_id')
    ->select('travel_request.*', 'department.name as dept_name','users.name as approver_name')->get();
```